# How to protect directory against getting committed changes when merging?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two directories in our Git repo, with a huge number (about 400) of commits divided between file updates in the two directories, although no commits are known to include changes to *both* directories within the same commit.

We need to merge commits from our feature branch into the master branch for *only one* of those directories, leaving files in the other directory untouched.  This means that we don't want about half the commits applied to master.

What is a recommended way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge individual commits, but you can [git cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) individual commits onto your master branch.  Use `git log` to figure out the SHA1s of the commits you want on master, and use git cherry-pick to apply them.

It's not an ideal solution, since cherry-pick introduces a new commit that's different than the original commit, and therefore you'll have what are essentially duplicate commits on your master and feature branches.  I try to avoid using cherry-pick.  It seems like it would solve your problem, but proceed with caution.

Comment: I originally planned to use cherry-pick but a couple problems with that approach was the huge number of commits, and also not knowing a way to only get the commits that were applied to the feature branch exclusively

Comment: You can use `git branch --contains <sha1>` to determine on which branches a commit is present.  But I agree, I wouldn't want to use cherry-pick on that many commits.

Comment: Thought about just making a copy of the directory I don't want updated and restoring it after merging the feature branch on top of it... but would I gain anything by doing a "git reset <sha1> directoryname; git checkout directoryname"?   We dont really want to add unnecessary deltas that will be subsequently cancelled out.

Comment: Another option is this.. `git merge --no-ff --no-commit featurebranch`, to merge your feature branch into master while giving you the chance to fix things, the same way you would if there was a merge conflict.  Then use `git checkout --ours -- directory-to-keep` to keep "directory-to-keep" intact.  Then commit the result.

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge all `dir1` changes in `msater..feature` to `master`.  Merge only cares about the content differences from the merge base to the merge tips, it doesn't care how you got there.  So, make a commit that has the correct merge base and only the content changes you want to merge:

```
git checkout -b feature-dir1-extract $(git merge-base master feature)
git checkout feature -- dir1
git commit -m "extracting dir1 changes from feature@$(git rev-parse feature)"
```

Now you've got all the changes you want, and you can merge just those:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-dir1-extract
```

This is enough to keep git straight on what content has been merged -- all of the current changes to `dir1` content in `feature` show up both there and in `master`, this is exactly what having a correct merge base is for -- but it might be easier for people reading the commit graph (via `git log --graph` or any of the gui tools) to also add a merge recording via ancestry rather than just unremarked fact that the same content is in both branches as of now:

```
git checkout feature
git merge feature-dir1-extract    # recording common content only, no changes
```

Regardless, the extract branch's name and history is now interesting only to people reading the commit histories themselves, and both name and history are recorded in the merge commits.  No need to keep advertising the name for everybody to pointlessly wonder about:

```
git branch -d feature-dir1-extract
```